# Python: (1) Looping input - (2) elaborated text - (3) continue code

Tags: python, input

I've 2 questions with the following code:

```
positive = {'yes','Yes','y','Y'}
negative = {'no','No''n','N'}
month = March

while True:
    a = input('The month that you want to archive is March' '(Y or N) ? ')
    if a=='N':
        input("You will now leave, press Enter......")
        break
    elif a=='Y':
        print("Let's do it")
        input("The archive will start now, press Enter......")
        continue
    else:
        print("Enter either 'Y' to continue or 'N' to leave")

print (month)
etc....
```

**Questions:**

1 - How can I accept the *input* as one of *positive* variable options ('yes','Yes','y','Y') ?

2 - How can I have the *month* variable written in the *input* question instead of March hardcoded (as it is in this moment)?

3 - I don't know how to keep running the code when users users press "Y" then Enter. It keeps repeating the question instead of running the *print(month)* code.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: Use [formatstrings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) to include variable content into string output.

Comment: You should take a look at this question and answer: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below solution resolves several problems with your code.

```
positive = {'yes','Yes','y','Y'}
negative = {'no','No', 'n','N'}
month = 'March'

while True:
    a = input('The month that you want to archive is {0}: (Y or N)?'.format(month))

    if a in negative:
        input("You will now leave, press Enter......")
        break

    elif a in positive:
        print("Let's do it")
        input("The archive will start now, press Enter......")
        # perform your tasks here
        break

    else:
        print("Enter either 'Y' to continue or 'N' to leave")
```

**Explanation**

- Test `a` versus the sets you have defined.
- Use `str.format` to incorporate a variable in your `input` string.
- Use `break` instead of `continue` to exit a loop after a positive value is entered; if you wish, you can include your "success" tasks inside the loop before `break`.

Comment: Thanks @jpp you answered the 3 questions :) cheers ;)

Answer (score 0):

That's one of the possible solutions (note that I am using list a list). If you want to support even more options without extending a list you might be interested in adding some [RegExp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

```
positive = ['yes','Yes','y','Y']
negative = ['no','No', 'n','N']
month = "March"

while True:
    a = input('The month that you want to archive is March' '(Y or N) ? ')

    if a in negative:
        input("You will now leave, press Enter......")
        break
    elif a in positive:
        print("Let's do it")
        input("The archive will start now, press Enter......")
        break
    else:
       print("Enter either 'Y' to continue or 'N' to leave")

 print (month)
```